# Can I update OpenSSL version of just one .so file

Tags: android, google-play, android-ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg based https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord project for my app. **Libavformat.so** file's version is **OpenSSL 1.0.2d** and Google Play requires minimum **1.0.2h**. How to update it? Or replace with another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check a perfect solution here:

https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord/issues/23